# Python: return between functions

Tags: python, arrays, list, return

I have one function that generates a list of strings, with 8 strings placed in it

```
def MajorScale(s):
    i = notes.index(s)
    t = i
    major_scale = []
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    t = t+2
    if t >= 12:
        t = t-12
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    t = t+2
    if t >= 12:
        t = t-12
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    t = t+1
    if t >= 12:
        t = t-12
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    t = t+2
    if t >= 12:
        t = t-12
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    t = t+2
    if t >= 12:
        t = t-12
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    t = t+2
    if t >= 12:
        t = t-12
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    t = t+1
    if t >= 12:
        t = t-12
    major_scale.append(notes[t])
    print(major_scale)
    return major_scale
```

The next function calls MajorScale and relies on the list major_scale to work

```
def MajorChord(s):
    MajorScale(s)
    major_chord = []
    major_chord.append(major_scale[0])
    major_chord.append(major_scale[2])
    major_chord.append(major_scale[4])
    print(major_chord)
```

However, when I run the program, I get an error saying "major_scale is not defined"

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point. If anyone can see the dumb mistake I'm making I'd love to find out.

Comment: You have used a capital 'M'.

Comment: in which case? I have a function called MajorScale, and a list called major_scale, but they are different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `MajorScale` returns a value, which you aren't saving to a variable in `MajorChord`.

```
def MajorChord(s):
    MajorScale(s)
    major_chord = []
    ...
```

So the return value is calculated and immediately thrown away. Put the return value into a variable like this in order to use it:

```
def MajorChord(s):
    major_scale = MajorScale(s)
    major_chord = []
    ...
```

Comment: Great! Don't remember to mark the answer as accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

you could use a list comprehension to make you code more readable

```
def MajorScale(note):
    i = notes.index(note)
    offsets = [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14]
    return [notes[(i+x)%12] for x in offsets]

def MajorChord(note):
    return MajorScale(note)[0:5:2]
```